# find first slash from the back ( file path )

Tags: php

I have this line.

```
$line = '/opt/fings/interface/20140905111645811106.txt 0';
```

I used this to trip the trailing `0/r/n`.

```
$pos = strpos($lines[$x], ' ');
$file = '.'.substr($lines[$x], 0, $pos);
```

so I'm left with this `/opt/fings/interface/20140905111645811106.txt`

But I need the filename alone.  e.g. `20140905111645811106.txt`

Ho do I grab the string from the back up to the first occurrence of a slash?

Comment: use basename() function to get 20140905111645811106.txt. e.g echo basename($line);

Comment: They're not called backslashes. `/` is a forward slash.

Comment: @mario - true - changed

Comment: check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: @oPi Thats FIRST occurence. I wanted last. But thanks.

Comment: @mornenel if there is a function for the FIRST, should be another for the LAST: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php. Its the first result looking in google

Comment: anyway, edit de Title to find last slash ( file path )

Comment: This is a XY question (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) and the correct title would be: How to get file name from full path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `basename()` in this case:

```
$line = '/opt/fings/interface/20140905111645811106.txt';
echo basename($line); // 20140905111645811106.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```
$str = '/opt/fings/interface/20140905111645811106.txt';
$file = end(explode('/',$str));
echo $file;
```

Output will be - `20140905111645811106.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Third decision

```
echo pathinfo ( '/opt/fings/interface/20140905111645811106.txt', PATHINFO_BASENAME  );
```

[pathinfo](http://php.net/pathinfo)

Answer (score 2):

Use `strrchr()` to find the last occurence of a character in a string.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php

`$position = strrchr($str, '/');`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this one

```
$text = '/opt/fings/interface/20140905111645811106.txt'
substr( strrchr( $text, '/' ), 1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, use `substr` and `strrpos`

```
$filename = substr($line, strrpos($line, "/")+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Through `preg_match`,

```
$line = '/opt/fings/interface/20140905111645811106.txt';
preg_match('~[^/]+$~', $line, $match);
echo $match[0]; // 20140905111645811106.txt
```